# Use same browser window in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

In my features file, I have something like this:

```
Background:
 Given I am on login screen
 Then I log in

Scenario:
 Given I am on a random account summary
 when I try feature-1
 Then I see some output-1

Scenario:
 Given I am on account summary
 When I try feature-2
 Then I see some message
```

When cucumber executes 2nd scenario, it re-executes the background.

My question is-
Is it possible to tell Cucumber to use the same browser session/state from previous scenario?
This will help my tests save some execution time.

Comment: Are you really sure you want your tests sharing state? You are aware that could cause any minor (possibly not failing) issue in one to corrupt the results of all the others? Generally, what you're asking for is a Very Bad Thing.

Comment: Your point is valid and under any normal circumstances I will try to avoid those. But my problem is that to test any feature, I need need to be logged in and reach a random account summary page. So, I was wondering if I could just do it one time and avoid atleast login process.

Answer (score 4):

Capybara resets sessions before each scenario so you should login explicitly before each of them. But as you don't test login in every scenario, I'd advice to automate this process.

At first, you can make your background more declariative:

```
Background:
 Given I'm logged in
```

Look at [this article](http://benmabey.com/2008/05/19/imperative-vs-declarative-scenarios-in-user-stories.html), it shows why it's better to do it.

Then you can:

1. Generate new session at back-end
2. Send session cookie from back-end to your test
3. Set cookie to Capybara. Capybara doesn't have cross-driver API for it so you can use:

[Webdriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Options.html#add_cookie-instance_method):

```
page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(name: 'name', value: 'value')
```

[Capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/pull/169#issuecomment-3544126):

```
page.driver.browser.set_cookie('c_user=asdasdasd; domain=.domain.com')
```

[Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#manipulating-cookies):

```
page.driver.set_cookie('name', 'value')
```

[RackTest](http://dobbse.net/thinair/2011/12/capybara-racktest-rspec-cookies-2of2.html) doesn't seem to fully support it. As a workaround you can do:

```
get new_service_request_path, {}, 'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'name=value'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will give this a try and comment again if I run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a number of options using Before and After hooks, as well as tagging. I'd start reading here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/hooks

Something like this:

```
Before do
   AccessRandomAccountPage() #Assumes you're logged in already
end
```

Or if this is specific to a set of tests, like you're "AlreadyLoggedIn" tests, you could use tagging:

```
Before ('@AlreadyLoggedIn') do
   AccessRandomAccountPage()
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In the your feature file, you are used the background:, it is executed for all scenario, to avoid to call every time([details of Background](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background)), please changes Background: into Scenario: and it is enough to tell Cucumber to use the same browser session from previous scenario

```
Scenario:
  Given I am on login screen
  Then I log in

Scenario:
 Given I am on a random account summary
 when I try feature-1
 Then I see some output-1

Scenario:
 Given I am on account summary
 When I try feature-2
 Then I see some message
```

Comment: Capybara resets sessions before each scenario so this way doesn't work